# Is this tautology

Tags: first-order-logic

I have this example:

$\lnot \exists y P(y) \to ( \forall y (\exists x P(x) \to P(y)))$

I am doing it step by step:

A: $\lnot \exists y P(y) \to ( \forall y (\exists x P(x) \to P(y)))$

B($\lnot$A) :$\lnot [\lnot \exists y P(y) \to ( \forall y (\exists x P(x) \to P(y)))]$

1: $\lnot \exists y P(y) \land \lnot ( \forall y (\exists x P(x) \to P(y)))$

2: $\forall \lnot y P(y) \land \exists y ( \lnot (\exists x P(x) \to P(y)))$

3: $\forall \lnot y P(y) \land \exists y ((\exists x P(x) \land \lnot  P(y)))$

4: $\forall \lnot y P(y) \land \exists y \exists x (( P(x) \land \lnot  P(y)))$

5: $\exists y \exists x [\forall \lnot z P(z) \land (( P(x) \land \lnot  P(y)))]$

6:  $\exists y \exists x \forall z[\lnot P(z) \land  P(x) \land \lnot  P(y)]$

7 SKOL(B):  $\forall z[\lnot P(z) \land  P(a) \land \lnot  P(b)]$

8: $C: =\lnot P(z) \land  P(a) \land \lnot  P(b)$

$\sum (C)=\{ \{ \lnot P(z)\} ,\{ P(a) \} , \{ \lnot  P(b) \} \}$

$gr(\sum (C))=\{ \{ \lnot P(b)\} ,\{ P(a) \} , \{ \lnot  P(b) \}... \}$

But i can't make empty clauseso its not tautology i guess.

$\{ \lnot P(b)\} ,\{ P(b) \} = $ empty clause (that's example)

In my case i cant make empty clause so i guess its not tautology, am i right?
Try to solve this formule on your own. 
Thank you for answers.

Comment: In steps numbered 1 through 5, the initial negation sign should be placed after the variable being quantified over. (I'm still sorting out the rest.  The method is new to me.)

Comment: But $\{ \lnot P(z) \}$ and $\{ P(a) \}$ produce the [empty clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)#Empty_clauses). See [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)): "The resolution rule is applied to all possible pairs of clauses that contain complementary literals. After each application of the resolution rule, the resulting sentence is simplified by removing repeated literals. If the sentence contains complementary literals, it is discarded (as a tautology). If after applying a resolution rule the empty clause is derived, the original formula is unsatisfiable."

Comment: It is enough to replace $z$ with $a$.

Comment: but "z" is stand for "y", "a" is stand for "x" so i think i cant make every where P(a). Cant i?
Is this example will be tautology guys?

Comment: As @MauroALLEGRANZA has pointed out, my answer (now deleted) was incorrect.  This is a tautology.

Comment: sr mate i think i click it by a mistake (im new here), guy u were right it is tautology. i didnt knew i can replace {z/a}.

Comment: "Informal proof"; consider @JimH's proposed transformation: $∃yP(y) ∨ (∀y(∃xP(x)→P(y)))$ and consider that, due to the fact that $y$ is not free in $∃xP(x)$, it is equivalent to: $∃yP(y) ∨ (∃xP(x)→∀yP(y))$. Two cases: either (i) there is some object that is $P$, in which case $∃yP(y)$ is *true*, and thus the disjunction holds, or (ii) there are no $P$s, in which case $∃yP(y)$ is *false* and thus the conditional $∃xP(x)→∀yP(y)$ is *true*, and again the disjunction holds.

Answer (score 2):

It's a weird formula: if no element satisfies $P$ (so the left hand side holds), then for all $y$ the implication $(\exists x P(x)) \to P(y)$ is true. (An implication with a false left hand side is always true). So I'd think  this is a tautology. You cannot make it false in some model.

Comment: Thank you mate for answer. Its one of my exam tasks. And we have to solve it in some steps. I will show you how when i edit post, so if u can, keep and eye on it :)

Comment: check it out now

Comment: @AdrianKowalski I'm not familiar with your method. But the comments deal with it I think.

Comment: is any difrent method to solve this formul, i mean to prove that is tautology or not? if is can u show me?

Comment: I reasoned about it in my answer.